# Filemaker Chart with Data from one field

Tags: filemaker

The records in the table I have all have a field "area". This field is connected to another table where there is also a name for this area.

All I'm trying to achieve is a chart that shows how often an area is present in the selected records in Y and have the name of the area in X.
I actually got the name in X but I can not for the life of me figure out which Calculation I need to use to get Filemaker to group the area_codes and tell me how often they appear and then show that value on the Y achses.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which Calculation I need to use to get Filemaker to group the
>   area_codes and tell me how often they appear

It's not a matter of calculation. You need to define a *summary field* as `Count of [ Area ]`.

Next, define your chart to `Use Data From: [ Current Found Set ]` and check the `Show data points for groups of records when sorted` option.

Use the summary field for the Y axis values and sort your records by the `Area` field.